# Conversion error In iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

Please see the below conversion and correct me:

```
dynamic AnnotationAction = (PdfDictionary)AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.A);
```

It's showing the following error:

> *"Cannot convert type 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRIndirectReference' to 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDictionary"*

Comment: Seems straightforward to me. The returned value from `Get(PdfName.A)` was **not** a `PdfDictionary` object, and there's no way to cast a `PRIndirectReference` object into a `PdfDictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code like this:

```
dynamic AnnotationAction = AnnotationDictionary.GetAsDict(PdfName.A);
```

You are assuming that the dictionary is added as a *direct object*. It's not. It's stored inside the PDF as an indirect object and you are retrieving a reference to that object instead of the actual object. This is explained in this book: http://itextpdf.com/pdfabc

Comment: Hi Bruno Thnaks I need One More help please see below Code Line.                                                        "dynamic AnnotationReferencedPage = PdfReader.GetPdfObject((PRIndirectReference)AnnotationAction.GetAsArray(PdfName.D).ArrayList(0));"   "It Showing Mentioned Error as                        "Non-invocable member 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfArray.ArrayList' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: It means you shouldn't use that method. Loop over the elements using `Size` and get the `PdfObject` instances one by one. Why? Because iTextSharp doesn't know what you expect when asking for the full array: do you want the references? or do you want the referenced objects? You need to make that choice yourself, hence you need to write the loop yourself.